# How to find out what is running an application in localhost?

Tags: macos, docker, kubernetes, apple-m1

I've been trying to learn and understand Docker and K8S during this month.

I've been following an extensive course for doing so.

Doing this course I've put up an application using Docker and K8S. This application is now running on my localhost. The problem is I don't know how to stop it from running.

When I do docker ps, I don't see anything related to this app.

I thought it's running because of a K8S deployment I created, so I made sure all the pods, services and deployments I've created are not running anymore. But the application is **still** running somehow.

How can I see **what** is running this application and stop it?
What else, other than a running container or a k8s cluster could be making this application run all the time?

I'm using Docker Desktop on Apple M1.

`docker ps`

Output:

```html
[aleksandralukic] ~  % docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
20e01a0aaf51   e704287ce753           "/storage-provisione…"   35 minutes ago   Up 35 minutes             k8s_storage-provisioner_storage-provisioner_kube-system_21cacbfa-1b50-423a-94e5-816f4f0ed7ca_12
d624d01d3a61   322111412cde           "kube-apiserver --ad…"   36 minutes ago   Up 36 minutes             k8s_kube-apiserver_kube-apiserver-docker-desktop_kube-system_4ac4b5ee26e7058a1ed090c12123e3a6_4
2da910c6ee11   699c5704c97f           "kube-controller-man…"   36 minutes ago   Up 36 minutes             k8s_kube-controller-manager_kube-controller-manager-docker-desktop_kube-system_77e9d7fdbb29bf4b5600ab5fbb368a2b_4
497f3c885919   62fbe881de53           "kube-scheduler --au…"   36 minutes ago   Up 36 minutes             k8s_kube-scheduler_kube-scheduler-docker-desktop_kube-system_57b58b3eb5589cb745c50233392349fb_7
0c42e63030ee   79da37e5a3aa           "/kube-vpnkit-forwar…"   36 minutes ago   Up 36 minutes             k8s_vpnkit-controller_vpnkit-controller_kube-system_f877ebc8-3fc1-4151-b6a3-4a6826a29ac1_6
1b73d52a95d5   05b738aa1bc6           "etcd --advertise-cl…"   40 minutes ago   Up 36 minutes             k8s_etcd_etcd-docker-desktop_kube-system_127f1e78367a800caa891919cc4b583f_4
1e9577931440   bf996869d15f           "/usr/local/bin/kube…"   47 hours ago     Up 47 hours               k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-rkn7n_kube-system_0f33f24b-4406-4fb2-843c-e9bf23053f79_2
e791b26133c2   db91994f4ee8           "/coredns -conf /etc…"   47 hours ago     Up 47 hours               k8s_coredns_coredns-f9fd979d6-ztgrf_kube-system_2d5a162a-e814-48b9-84b1-4b7b1d1c4bf7_4
523b4db5f44e   db91994f4ee8           "/coredns -conf /etc…"   47 hours ago     Up 47 hours               k8s_coredns_coredns-f9fd979d6-hw6hm_kube-system_17b7e5a8-eeae-4e95-a5d4-4c66386a8ea1_4
83c8257b41f8   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2   "/pause"                 47 hours ago     Up 47 hours               k8s_POD_vpnkit-controller_kube-system_f877ebc8-3fc1-4151-b6a3-4a6826a29ac1_2
1fad40204931   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2   "/pause"                 47 hours ago     Up 47 hours               k8s_POD_coredns-f9fd979d6-hw6hm_kube-system_17b7e5a8-eeae-4e95-a5d4-4c66386a8ea1_2
3fcd09a456a6   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2   "/pause"                 47 hours ago     Up 47 hours               k8s_POD_storage-provisioner_kube-system_21cacbfa-1b50-423a-94e5-816f4f0ed7ca_2
88e6b4cfbf3e   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2   "/pause"                 47 hours ago     Up 47 hours               k8s_POD_coredns-f9fd979d6-ztgrf_kube-system_2d5a162a-e814-48b9-84b1-4b7b1d1c4bf7_3
39693a90ea81   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2   "/pause"                 47 hours ago     Up 47 hours               k8s_POD_kube-proxy-rkn7n_kube-system_0f33f24b-4406-4fb2-843c-e9bf23053f79_2
fcc41117113b   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2   "/pause"                 47 hours ago     Up 47 hours               k8s_POD_kube-scheduler-docker-desktop_kube-system_57b58b3eb5589cb745c50233392349fb_3
da2a9f54d5ff   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2   "/pause"                 47 hours ago     Up 47 hours               k8s_POD_kube-controller-manager-docker-desktop_kube-system_77e9d7fdbb29bf4b5600ab5fbb368a2b_3
dae0c435c4ae   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2   "/pause"                 47 hours ago     Up 47 hours               k8s_POD_kube-apiserver-docker-desktop_kube-system_4ac4b5ee26e7058a1ed090c12123e3a6_2
e2e3ca8570bd   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2
```

```
kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces
```

Output:

```html
[aleksandralukic] ~  % kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system   coredns   2/2     2            2           4d21h
```

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

```html
[aleksandralukic] Projects/TestFrameworks/serenity-portfolio-project on branch feature % kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME             CLUSTER          AUTHINFO         NAMESPACE
*         docker-desktop   docker-desktop   docker-desktop
```

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

```html
[aleksandralukic] Projects/TestFrameworks/serenity-portfolio-project on branch feature % kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-f9fd979d6-hw6hm                  1/1     Running   5          5d19h
kube-system   coredns-f9fd979d6-ztgrf                  1/1     Running   5          5d19h
kube-system   etcd-docker-desktop                      1/1     Running   5          5d19h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-docker-desktop            1/1     Running   5          5d19h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-docker-desktop   1/1     Running   5          5d19h
kube-system   kube-proxy-rkn7n                         1/1     Running   3          5d19h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-docker-desktop            1/1     Running   8          5d19h
kube-system   storage-provisioner                      1/1     Running   14         5d19h
kube-system   vpnkit-controller                        1/1     Running   7          5d19h
```

Output of:

```
netstat -b
```

doesn't explain what is running on my 31515 port since I don't see it listed. So if it's not running in docker or k8s and it's not listed in the network statistics, how can I know what is running it?

Comment: When you say it's running "on localhost", which one?  Each Docker container and each Kubernetes pod believes it is localhost, plus each Kubernetes node will also believe it is localhost.  The Docker and Kubernetes tools don't usually produce image files as their output, and you might edit your question to include a [mcve] and those commands' outputs as text (not images) directly in the question (not behind links).

Comment: OK, I'll modify my question. This is the full IP of my running application: http://127.0.0.1:31515/

Comment: You mentioned "so I made sure all the pods, services and deployments I've created are not running anymore". Did you [delete somer resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#deleting-resources)? Secondly how did you check that your application is still running? Did you refresh page with your app?

Comment: Yes, previously I've deleted some deployments that I've created during the course. I imagined that with the deletion of resources that were running the application, it will stop running. But it didn't. I can see it running in the browser. I refreshed the page many times.

Comment: @Aleksandra Lukić, it looks like your application is running locally on the machine, not on kubernetes. Have you run it before not in Kubernetes? Could you also attach output of `kubectl get pods --all namespaces`?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak Unfortunately don't remember how I ran the application for the first time. I was following along a docker + K8s course for a whole month and the setting up of the app was somewhere in the beginning. Attached the output you asked in the questions.

Comment: @AleksandraLukić, thanks! Probably your application is running locally. To confirm this, restart the cluster. Docker Desktop has a feature to tear down your whole Kubernetes cluster and reset it to the original state. Open the settings from the Docker whale icon and click Kubernetes. Click the Reset Kubernetes Cluster button and the demo app will be gone. If the application continues to run after rebooting, it means it was not launched via Kubernetes. Can you tell me what course did you watch?

Comment: I confirm that after restarting it's not running on Kubernetes. So I have to find out how am I running it locally.  This is the course I watched: https://www.udemy.com/share/101WReB0Aed1ZVRno=/

Answer (score 0):

Try `kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces` to search across [namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/). Also note that a pod may have been created independently (that is, without a deployment) or using a stateful set, so if the above yields no results, try `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`.

You should also make sure you are using the right kubectl context using `kubectl config get-contexts`.

Comment: The only deployment accross all namespaces I have is the kube-system. The pods I have are all pods that belong to that namespace, and none of them seem to be running this application. When I get the context, all I see is docker-desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Checking Pods, Deplyoments and Containers clearly suggests that your application is not running on Kubernetes. As the discussion in the comment section shows, the application still works even after restarting the cluster. This means it is running locally.

If you want to check what is running on port `31515` you can execute this command:

```
netstat -vanp tcp | grep 31515
```

or:

```
lsof -i tcp:31515
```

It is very possible that you launched this application at the beginning of the course locally and then on kubernetes. In this case, check the course and try to disable the application.

Answer (score 0):

I **fixed this issue** after experiencig it while talking the same course.
Thought that I'd add my fix in case someone sees this down the line.

For some reason `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` and `kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces` did not show anything running that could still display the app in my browser on localhost:31515.

I eventually went through all older file and remembered I had config file that used port 31515. I did some testing by changing the container in the config file and used `kubectl apply -f "config file name"` and found the app in the browser changed. which confirmed it was running lcaolly somewhere.

I then used `kubectl delete -f "config file name"` which terminated it and the app no longer showed in the browser after refresh.

you can also use `kubectl delete -f "folder name"` to stop all things running using config files in that folder/directory.

On an important sidenote specific to this course, one of the apps you are looking for is hosted on **localhost:80** not 31515. this is when using ingress-nginx.